# SonataUserBundle override model

Tags: symfony, symfony-sonata

How to delete unwanted fileds in the entity/model: facebook, twitter, bio, website from the Model/User.php ?

I try to ovveride the Model but it doesn't work.

I succed to override the entity, i added some new property, and it work, but want to delete unwanted stuff.

Thx, bye

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in fact, i got it.
I must to extend the model, not the entity, and it works !!!
I can remove unwanted stuff

Answer (score 0):

You can create own user entity which will not extend SonataUserBundle User.php class.
If you used FOSUSerBundle:

```
class User extends FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User
```

or you can extend by default Symfony 2 Security User.php class.

Next you can configure SonataUserBundle to use your user entity:

```
sonata_user:
    class:
        user: MyBundle\Entity\User
```

Full configuration is here:

https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/reference/advanced_configuration.rst

If you used SonataUserBundle default controller to manage users you need to create own UserAdmin Class and configure sonata:

```
sonata_user:
    admin:                  # Admin Classes
        user:
            class:          MyBundle\Admin\UserAdmin
```

Comment: i use sonatauserbundle as my own default class user, i override it, but wanna just delete unwanted stufff...it seem not possible in my configuration